# Erasing from an STL container by a constant iterator

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, iterator, containers

According the the [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) STL containers were fixed in C++11 standard to take constant iterator in the `erase` methods. The following code would not compile in g++4.7 with `c++0x` enabled.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vector;
    vector.push_back(0);

    std::vector<int>::const_iterator vectorItr = vector.begin();
    vector.erase(vectorItr);
}
```

Obviously the new signatures were not implemented. Is there any information when this issue will be fixed? I could not find any respective information in the [C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) article.

Comment: `auto it = vector.cbegin();` if you don't like the long iterator name. ;)

Comment: [GCC 4.8 with `-std=c++11`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1dc94c991c3d6f8fcfbd87674f882de9-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: @Xeo: Using just "auto" here would not make vectorIter a const_iterator which is what was intended.

Comment: @sellibitze note about `cbegin()`, cbegin() returns const_iterator in all cases.

Comment: @ForEveR: Oh, right. I didn't see that little extra character Xeo's comment. Sorry, for the trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [**HERE**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x):

> *Section:* **23.3.6**
>   *Description:* Class template vector
>   *Status:* **Partial**
>   *Comments:* insert and erase members do not take const_iterator arguments (N2350).

Comment: Thank you! Now I know where to get a detailed information about C++11.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth: I've tested this against GCC 4.8.1 as well as GCC 4.9 (20130602 snapshot) just now, and the result is that 4.8.1 still has this problem (note that the promised C++11 compliance is related to the language core, not the standard library), but the 4.9 snapshot compiles it correctly.

So I guess it's fair to assume that GCC 4.9, once released, will handle this as specified by the Standard.

Comment: @Kolyunya so do I :) (for experimental use and if you are ok to build it yourself, the snapshots are already available)

Comment: I would be so incredibly happy if I could use a native g++ on unix, but I'm being forced to use mingw on win...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at gcc's [library implementation status](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x). There it clearly states that the feature in question hasn't been implemented yet:

> 23.3.6 - Class template vector - Partial - insert and erase members do not take const_iterator arguments (N2350).

Comment: Thank you! Now I know where to get a detailed information about C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Unsurprisingly: because it has not been implemented yet it seems ([even in C++11 mode](http://ideone.com/qA31fo)).

The simplest way for you to check is to have a peek at the underlying implementation of `std::vector`. Though most of it can be quite arcane, method signatures are usually easy enough to read.

Answer (score 1):

Full C++11 compliance is given in GCC 4.8 (not 4.7).

Since 4.7 is not granted to be full compliant, this cannot be considered (In strict technical terms) an "error". May be it was a need to retain some compatibility with other library modules not compliant yet.

If this happens in 4.8 then it has to be considered a bug. But not in 4.7